# Created Service with accessibility service but unable to stop it

Tags: android, android-layout, service, android-service, accessibilityservice

I have created a service. When I start it from MainActivity its started but when I click on button to stop it it's doesn't stop. It is working fine in lower version devices but only issue found in Android 10 or higher versions.

```
   public void startServices() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PerformTaskService.class);
    startService(intent);
   }


   public void stopServices() {
    stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PerformTaskService.class));
  }
```

**PerformTaskService.java**

```
public class PerformTaskService extends Service {
String TAG = "ServiceStatus";

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

int id;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    this.id = startId;
    Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand: "+startId );
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    stopSelfResult(id);
    stopSelf(id);
    new StatusBarService().onDestroy();
    stopSelf();
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

**StatusBarService.java**

```
public class StatusBarService extends AccessibilityService {
int id;

@Override
public ComponentName startForegroundService(Intent service) {
    return super.startForegroundService(service);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    this.id = startId;
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@SuppressLint({"InflateParams", "InlinedApi"})
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    View mFloatingView = 
LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.layout_floating_widget, 
null);
    thumbView = 
LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.layout_seekbar_thumb, 
null, false);
    deviceManger = ((DevicePolicyManager) 
getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE));
}

@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {

}

@Override
public void onInterrupt() {

}

public void deviceadminCheck() {
 Intent intent = new 
 Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    stopSelf();
    stopSelf(id);
    stopSelfResult(id);
    super.onDestroy();
    }
 }
```

So, kindly let me know if you have any proper solution or Idea about this issue. how to stop service

Comment: "when I click on button to stop it it's doesn't stop" -- what is your definition of "stop" and how *precisely* have you determined that it does not stop? Beyond that, get rid of `new StatusBarService().onDestroy()` will work on approximately zero Android devices. **Never create an instance of an activity or service yourself**. I would expect that code to  crash, because the `Service` instance was not initialized correctly by the framework.

Comment: First I tried stopservice(intent) but it not worked for me. SO I tried to create this new instance so I can call destroy method. I got destroy method from this instance but still service is running.

Comment: How do you know that your `Service` is not stopped? What happens when you call `stopService()`

Comment: i make some function while service is started and function is continues working while app is destroyed so I know that  service is still running.